# QR decoding on android using ZXing

Tags: android, qr-code

Can anyone please guide me on how to do this. So far I understand that I can create an intent, then call the "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" action, however this is only works with barcodes, I need to implement it using QR codes, can anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: ZXing works perfectly well with QR codes, usually with no changes to your app. Use the `IntentIntegrator` code per the documentation: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent Here is a sample project illustrating this, including a compiled copy of `IntentIntegrator`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to add is an extra into the intent for QR

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
```

But, the comment on your answer is right, it shouldn't matter.  This should only make the scan alittle faster

Cheers